# Converting row of DataFrame to a Series (Pandas)

Tags: pandas

So I could not find how to do this in the documentation, but I am reading a row from a dataframe as such:

```
self.data = df[n:n+1]
```

But this results in self.data being a 1 row and 7 column dataframe, instead of just a series. However, the test cases for my course depend on it being a series. Is there an easy way to make that conversion?

Comment: can't you just call `squeeze()`?

Answer (score 3):

Just use `.ix`:

```
df.ix[n]
```

That assumes that your `df.index` lists the rows in numerical order.